# Stats for a wp powered intranet

Tags: plugin-recommendation, local-installation, statistics

I'm currently building a simple intranet powered by WordPress. I need to show the stats (most read articles, user logins, etc..) to the administrator, but I can't use google analytics as the install is on a VPN without internet access.

Do you know any reliable plugin to record and show stats on a local install of WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend installing Piwik on your intranet using one of their plugins, though it will work just fine as a stand alone.

http://piwik.org/
http://piwik.org/blog/2008/06/new-plugin-wordpress-piwik-integration/

Comment: Is it confirmed that piwik works offline? Also, it's in English right?